# SQL Server Select alias with IN statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, alias

I have the following `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT t.ID, 
       t.SiteID, 
       t.SpareID, 
       t.SpareLocationID, 
       t.Qty, 
       t.IsDefault
  FROM TrainingDB.dbo.LocationsPerSpare t
 WHERE t.SpareID IN
       (SELECT s.SpareID
          FROM TrainingDB.dbo.LocationsPerSpare s
         WHERE s.SpareLocationID = t.SpareLocationID
           AND s.SpareID = t.SpareID
         GROUP BY s.SpareID
        HAVING COUNT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), s.SpareID)) > 2)
 ORDER BY t.SpareID
```

If I execute that script, it returns `NULL`. However, if I remove the `t.` alias as below, it runs normally.

```
SELECT ID, 
       SiteID, 
       SpareID, 
       SpareLocationID, 
       Qty, 
       IsDefault
  FROM TrainingDB.dbo.LocationsPerSpare 
 WHERE SpareID IN
       (SELECT s.SpareID
          FROM TrainingDB.dbo.LocationsPerSpare s
         WHERE s.SpareLocationID = SpareLocationID
           AND s.SpareID = SpareID
         GROUP BY s.SpareID
        HAVING COUNT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), s.SpareID)) > 2)
 ORDER BY SpareID
```

I find this quite strange. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove

```
AND s.SpareID = t.SpareID
```

from your sub query.  You're using the subquery to filter the values of SpareID in the main query when SpareID doesn't yet have a value.

Comment: Also, I would add that the reason the 2nd query works is that `s.SpareID = SpareID` is essentially `1 = 1`.  Same goes for SpareLocationID. Of course they equate.

Comment: Close. Removing s.SpareLocationID = t.SpareLocationID works. Thanks for your response. The puzzling thing though, is that without the "t." alias, it works properly.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I use Oracle more frequently, and I don't have these issues there. No alias wouldn't imply 1=1 as you put it. But thats useful to know.

Comment: Sorry, 1=1 meaning that `s.SpareID = SpareID` is the same as writing `SpareID = SpareID` or `s.SpareID = s.SpareID`.  See what I mean? Its evaluating against the same row.

Comment: I understood what you meant. In Oracle, t.SpareID = SpareID would not be the same. Thanks for taking the trouble to reply.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can rewrite this query without the join, using window functions instead:

```
select lps.ID, lps.SiteID, lps.SpareID, lps.SpareLocationID, 
       lps.Qty, lps.IsDefault
from (select lps.*,
             count(*) over (partition by spareId) as SpareCnt
      from TrainingDB.dbo.LocationsPerSpare lps
     ) lps
where SpareCnt > 2
```

The reason you need the alias is because unaliased columns in a subquery are assigned to the table at the nearest reference.  So,

```
 where s.SpareID = t.SpareID
```

compares the SpareId from the outer table reference to the inner one.

```
 where s.SpareID = SpareID
```

First determines which table `SpareID` comes from.  It matches a column in the inner subquery, so it uses that.  The expression is equivalent to:

```
where s.SpareID = s.SpareId
```

And finally, the user of `convert` with `count` is totally unnecessary.  `Count` is just counting the number of non-NULL values, and this does not change when converting to a string.

For instance, when I test this code, it works fine:

```
declare @t uniqueidentifier = newid();

select count(distinct t)
from (select @t as t) v
```

Although, interestingly, this code doesn't work on SQLFiddle.  But there is is giving the error that `@t` is undefined, which is unrelated.

Comment: Very interesting Gordon, thanks for the response. However, the SpareID is a Unique Identifier, and I received a error message forcing me to use CONVERT.